# Close modal and load new url?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I am using [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to launch a modal window on my site. In the modal a SurveyMonkey survey loads. At the end of the survey, depending on how people answer it, they will be offered a link to click. When clicked, we need to CLOSE the modal and then load a new page in the main site under the modal. Is there a way to do that by clicking a link in the modal?

THANKS for your help and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

```
// put it in the base document
    $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
            // navigate to new URI in a prefered way
    });


// a little different way to achieve same result
$(".example9").colorbox(
{
    onClosed:function()
    {
        // navigate to new URI in a prefered way
    }
});
```

**Additional example.**

HTML:

```
<a id="base" href="#">Show colorbox</a>
<div style='display: none'>
        <div id='divModal' style='padding: 10px; background: #fff; border: 1px solid red; z-index=100;'>This is test
            <a id="google" href="#">google.com</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('a#base').colorbox({inline: false, href:'#divModal', width: "150px", height: "100px"});

$('a#google').click(
    function()
    {
        $.colorbox.close();
        window.location = 'google.com';
    }
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Could you please elaborate? Is that code in the Colorbox js file? I am not fluent in Javascript so if you could be more clear, that would be really helpful. I am not sure how this works. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Use it in a parent html file where you launch ColorBox window. Also you can find al little different syntax in an example: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html. "Example with alerts" link do exactly what you need. In the source you can view code that show alert when you close ColorBox. I've changed my code sample above to show one more way call onClose event.

Comment: Still not working. I cannot figure this out. Please try my test site. You'll have to answer 3 questions in the survey to get to end. Question #1 - NO, Question #2, select anything, Question #3 - NO. Then you will see a link for Google as an example. When the Google link is clicked, I need the modal to close and launch Google in the parent browser window below the modal.  http://www.careersinmusic.com/music-career-finder-launch.aspx I am even willing to Paypal someone some cash to get this working for me.

Comment: Make link like this: <a href="#" onClick="$.colorbox.close()">google.com</a>.

Comment: I'll do it for free. Give me ftp-access to any directory on your server and put music-career-finder-launch.aspx in it. So I'll be able to quick online check. My e-mail: lex AT rwx.com.ua

Comment: I have writen some examples and sent you a link to it.